# Sniffing twisted pair without interupt

Tags: oscilloscope, cables, network, twisted-pair

Is it possible, with an oscilloscope, scalpel and a lot of patient, to open up a network cable (twisted pair), and sniff the traffic? All without interrupting the network traffic.

So;

- Use the scalpel to get inside the cables, one by one.
- Use the oscilloscope to find out which cable does what.
- Attach to the data cables and dump the packages.

Or will this disturb/beak the connection and make it unstable/impossible for the ends to talk to each others.

Comment: I guess if you had differential high impedance probes, and proper logic analyser equipment, sure. To do it properly you would need good quality equipment though, but i'm not sure.

Comment: The wires inside the cable are usually color coded, so no need for guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible in theory, but will be difficult in practise.  One problem is that anything you attach to the cable will cause a impedance discontinuity, which can cause problems with the regular communication.  Depending on the situation, it also allows the right kind of sniffer to figure out you're in there eavesdropping.

You want to put a relatively high resistance immediately connected to the cable.  This resistance needs to be significantly higher than the impedance of the cable.  For example, if you're breaking into normal ethernet, then the cable impedance is 50 Ω.  You'd want to put at least 500 Ω resistors immediately on the lines so that your tap is contributing little in terms of impedance discontinuity.

However, the higher the frequency of the signals, the harder it will be to still make sense of the signals at the other end of the resistors.  This is where you may have to carefully create a circuit, physically close to the resistors, to receive the signal.  Once you interpret the signal into digital, you can then transport it by ordinary means to whatever you have decoding the data stream.

Answer (score 1):

If you used a couple of [these](http://www.tek.com/datasheet/current-probe/ct1-%E2%80%A2-ct2-%E2%80%A2-ct6-0) - or similar - you wouldn't have to strip the insulation from the individual conductors, all you'd have to do would be to remove a little of the cable's jacket and clamp around the [insulated] conductors of interest.

An added - perhaps life-saving - bonus would be that your eavesdropping would be virtually undetectable.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this and it works, at least for 10/100 megabit Ethernet. So long as you splice straight through (NOT a Y-shaped cable) reflections aren't a critical issue. You can just chop it in half, strip the wires, and solder to a piece of Veroboard. This probably won't work if your cable is also 300m long, but along a bench it works fine. It may not work for gigabit.

I had to do this to debug broken autonegotiation: two devices that would talk to each other directly but refused to work via a switch. The "fast link pulses" were clearly visible on a scope; I think it was a 100MHz scope, modern but not especially fancy.

(Quite a lot of things will work OK without nice controlled impedance setups provided they're in a nice quiet lab and not being pushed hard. I had a collection of USB cables with other connectors spliced into the middle for test purposes, including FFC which we ultimately chose to use).

Comment: If your impedance discontinuity is relatively close to one of the existing endpoints, its effect will be minimized.